# how to set preferable audio language in Totem (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, video, totem

How to set preferable audio language in Totem (Ubuntu)?

When playing list of movies with 2 languages (Russian and Japanese) Japanese is always selected for some reason. I want to set that Russian channel should be selected by default.

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 0):

You just need to right click on the playing video and choose the other language option. That is what i did and all is good for my case it was japanese english.